# Creating time variables for conditional risk set model (Cox regression)

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm preparing a dataset to a fit a conditional risk set model by using stratified Cox regression. And I was wondering whether there is any way to create the variables I need without running time-consuming loops.

Basically, my data frame is like this, showing whether and when a given country (`ID`) has experienced some event during a specific time period:

```
 year    ID event   time
 1991    UK     0      1
 1992    UK     0      2
 1993    UK     0      3
 1994    UK     0      4
 1995    UK     0      5
 1996    UK     0      6
 1997    UK     0      7
 1998    UK     0      8

 1991    FR     0      1
 1992    FR     1      2
 1993    FR     1      3
 1994    FR     0      4
 1995    FR     0      5
 1996    FR     1      6
 1997    FR     0      7
 1998    FR     0      8

 1991    IT     1      1
 1992    IT     0      2
 1993    IT     0      3
 1994    IT     0      4
 1995    IT     0      5
 1996    IT     1      6
 1997    IT     0      7
 1998    IT     0      8
```

I need to create two more variables: a *conditional time* variable, similar to `time`, but 'resetting the clock' each time an event occurs; and a *sequence* variable that indicates in which sequence or stage is the country, i.e., whether the next event would be the second, third, fourth... (the number should increase *after* the event). Thus, the data would look like this:

```
 year    ID event   time cond.time sequence
 1991    UK     0      1         1        1
 1992    UK     0      2         2        1
 1993    UK     0      3         3        1
 1994    UK     0      4         4        1
 1995    UK     0      5         5        1
 1996    UK     0      6         6        1
 1997    UK     0      7         7        1
 1998    UK     0      8         8        1

 1991    FR     0      1         1        1
 1992    FR     1      2         2        1
 1993    FR     1      3         1        2
 1994    FR     0      4         1        3
 1995    FR     0      5         2        3
 1996    FR     1      6         3        3
 1997    FR     0      7         1        4
 1998    FR     0      8         2        4

 1991    IT     1      1         1        1
 1992    IT     0      2         1        2
 1993    IT     0      3         2        2
 1994    IT     0      4         3        2
 1995    IT     0      5         4        2
 1996    IT     1      6         5        2
 1997    IT     0      7         1        3
 1998    IT     0      8         2        3
```

Anyone knows how could this be done in some efficient way? I was trying to do it with the `ddply` function, but didn't find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table` package. If `df` is your original `data.frame`:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[,temp:=ifelse(is.na(lag(event,1)), as.integer(0), lag(event,1)), by=ID]
dt[, sequence:=cumsum(temp)+1, by=ID]

func = function(x)
{
    which(c(1,lag(x,1)[-1]) %in% 1) %>%
    c(length(x)+1) %>% 
    diff
}

dt[, cond.time:=func(event) %>% lapply(seq) %>% unlist, by=ID]

> dt
    year ID event time temp sequence cond.time
 1: 1991 UK     0    1    0        1         1
 2: 1992 UK     0    2    0        1         2
 3: 1993 UK     0    3    0        1         3
 4: 1994 UK     0    4    0        1         4
 5: 1995 UK     0    5    0        1         5
 6: 1996 UK     0    6    0        1         6
 7: 1997 UK     0    7    0        1         7
 8: 1998 UK     0    8    0        1         8
 9: 1991 FR     0    1    0        1         1
10: 1992 FR     1    2    0        1         2
11: 1993 FR     1    3    1        2         1
12: 1994 FR     0    4    1        3         1
13: 1995 FR     0    5    0        3         2
14: 1996 FR     1    6    0        3         3
15: 1997 FR     0    7    1        4         1
16: 1998 FR     0    8    0        4         2
17: 1991 IT     1    1    0        1         1
18: 1992 IT     0    2    1        2         1
19: 1993 IT     0    3    0        2         2
20: 1994 IT     0    4    0        2         3
21: 1995 IT     0    5    0        2         4
22: 1996 IT     1    6    0        2         5
23: 1997 IT     0    7    1        3         1
24: 1998 IT     0    8    0        3         2
```

Comment: Yes, that totally worked! Even though I had to change the lag function to this one (from [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/14suqk/lag_function_in_r/)):


`reglag = function(x,lag) {c(rep(NA,lag), x[lag:(length(x)-1)])}`